# how can the append count the index each time and when remove it can reset the entire index in js

Tags: javascript

**how can the append count the index each time and when remove it can reset the entire index in js**

```
$('button#add_ticket').click(function(e) {
                $('#ticket_content').append(
                    `<div class="partials">
                        <div class="heading">
                            <div class='box'>
                                <div>
                                    test
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button onclick="removeRow(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
                )
            })
    
            function removeRow(e) {
                e.parentElement.parentNode.parentElement.remove();
            }
```

**here is the code**

```
<div id='ticket_content'></div>
<button id='add_ticket' type="button"></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use JS and index for counting your appended elements, you can simply use CSS:
[MDN - Using_CSS_counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

```js
$('#add_ticket').on("click", function(e) {
  $('#ticket_content').append(
    `<div class="partials__box">
        <div class="heading d-flex">
            <div class='box-header'>
                <div class='header-box bases__text-bold bases__font--18'>
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='box-header'>
                <button onclick="removeRow(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body"></div>
    </div>`
  );
});

function removeRow(el) {
  $(el).closest(".partials__box").remove();
}
```

```css
#ticket_content {
  counter-reset: ticket;  
}

.partials__box::before {
  counter-increment: ticket;  
  content: counter(ticket) ". "; 
}
```

```html
<div id='ticket_content'></div>
<button id='add_ticket' type="button">ADD</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how can I get the value of content calculated by counter ?

Comment: @MRCC by using JavaScript and `indexOf` or with jQuery's `.index()` i.e: `const i = $(".partials__box").index(this)` where `this` is the `.partials__box` you're interested in.

Comment: I tried at the removeRow function but am not getting the index? can you give me an example ?